# Using SHA-256 algorithm in Microsoft JScript

Tags: jscript

I have to represent this node.js code in Microsoft Jscript. How can I do that?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var value = 'helloworld';
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(value).digest('hex')
```